# I need to add more and more <timepicker> for an irrigation schedule, an idea?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

It is in javascript, and I use cloneNode(), the clone it's created but "time-picker" not work.

```
addSchedule() {
    var time_picker = document.getElementById("time");
    var clone = time_picker.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("schedule").appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: use *ngFor to repeat them, cloning a bit of dome is not going to create new instances of the timepicker component.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: I have a little problem, i repeat them as you said, but its not working properly, if i changed the time in one of them, it change in all. And all has a different id. An idea to make the work properly?

Comment: making a new question with the current code would be the way to go. :)

Comment: most likely you are binding all time pickers to the same model and one gets changed it changes all of them.

Comment: you were right, the model was the problem!  Thank you!